# URL friendly ASP Classic and Isapi Rewrite

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, asp-classic, web-config, plesk

The point is, I can access an address `dominio.com/modulo/id/titulo` and it rewrites to `dominio.com/default.asp?link=artigo&id=123&titulo=teste`, but my question is whether I can do the reverse process, i.e. go to `dominio.com/default.asp?link=artigo&id=123&titulo=teste` and it changes to `dominio.com/modulo/id/titulo`.

**Codes:**

**ASP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="pt-br"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><title>Teste Isapi Rewrite</title></head><body><p>Teste!<br>link: <%=request("link")%><br>id: <%=request("id")%><br>teste: <%=request("teste")%><br></p></body></html>
```

**WEB.CONFIG**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="artigo" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^artigo/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$" />
                <conditions> 
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> 
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> 
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="default.asp?link={R:0}&amp;id={R:1}&amp;teste={R:2}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: `Server.Transfer url`?

Comment: @Lankymart from what I researched does not work in this case

Comment: I don't understand how your friendly url would work. I don't see where `modulo` comes from, and `id` and `titulo` are the names of querystring variables, not the values. `dominio.com/artigo/123/teste` would correspond to `dominio.com/default.asp?link=artigo&id=123&titulo=teste`

Comment: @John exact. The form you quoted already works with the code I put in the question. But I would like to work in reverse too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use below url rewrite rule:

```
 <rule name="reverse" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="default.asp" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="link=(.*)\&amp;id=(.*)\&amp;titulo=(.*)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{C:1}/{C:2}/{C:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>


            <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="default.asp?link={R:1}&amp;id={R:2}&amp;titulo={R:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

default page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Teste Isapi Rewrite</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Teste!<br>link: <%=request("link")%><br>id: <%=request("id")%><br>titulo: <%=request("titulo")%><br></p>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: it didn't work for me, normal access but still the original link

Comment: do you want to change the site URL or the page content? could you please explain your requirement in detail again?

Comment: I only want to change the URL. Today my application opens as follows: www.domain.com/default.asp?link=test&id=123&title=title%20test. I want to change this URL to www.domain.com/test/123/title-test.

Comment: So open with `www.domain.com/default.asp?link=test&id=123&title=title%20test` and show `www.domain.com/test/123/title-test`

Comment: I am checking. I will probably have to make some adjustments to the application because of the js, css, etc. dependencies, but it looks like it will work.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're after is a rule which redirects the "unfriendly" URL to the "friendly" one - ie if you paste the unfriendly one into your browser address bar then it changes to the friendly one when your page appears in the screen.  Janvi Panchal has the right idea above.  What you do is have a redirect rule and a rewrite rule as follows.

```
<rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^dominio\.com/default\.asp$" />
     <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^link=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;id=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;titulo=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Redirect" url="dominio.com/default/{C:1}/{C:2}/{C:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^dominio\.com/default/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
     <conditions>
         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="dominio.com/default.asp?link={R:1}&amp;id={R:2}&amp;titulo={R:3}" />
 </rule>
```

Note that the redirect rule comes first, so what's happening is that the location is redirected to the friendly URL which is then rewritten as the unfriendly one.

Also note that I didn't hand code this - I generated it with the URL rewrite wizard in IIS Manager.  Click on the URL Rewrite icon, then Add Rule then User Friendly URL. Check the "Create corresponding redirect rule" before you click the OK button and this code will be generated and appended to your web.config file in the appropriate location